# How to determine the integrating factor for a non-exact differential equation? µ(xy)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(3x+\frac6y) + (\frac{x^2}y +\frac{3y}x)y'=0$$
$$ \mu = \mu(xy) $$

I am unsure of how to calculate the integrating factor which depends on x and y. I attempted to solve using $(\mu M)_y = (\mu N)_x $ but I could not figure out how to solve this problem. I know the answer is $\mu = xy $, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Do the calculations taking into account that $\mu$ depends on $x\,y$:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\,\mu(x\,y)=y\,\mu'(x\,y),\quad\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\,\mu(x\,y)=x\,\mu'(x\,y).
$$